# gatling jsonPath partial string match

Tags: regex, scala, performance-testing, gatling

**My full code is as below**

```
 val TC04 = feed(accountNumberFeeder04).exec(http(testCase04).post(appendPathToUrl).headers(common_header).body(postPayload).asJSON
    .check(jsonPath("$..errorMessage").is(errorMessage04))
   )
```

So my HTTP response have a some dynamic text.

say *`bla bla bla`* part in my message is get changed every time.

So, How can I match partial string using Gatling DSL or using some regex expressions.

```
.check(jsonPath("My error message is bla bla bla ....").is("My error message"))
```

Comment: Please post more context. What libraries does this code use? Are you developing with Play framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can  express the correct jsonPath but the .is() condition is too restrictive you can try with .exists() which simply checks if anything in given jsonPath was matched.